# Javascript in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have the following code to add, edit and delete user. Add function works fine but edit and delete functions are not working. I'm not sure where it goes wrong.

application/view/userlist.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function()
{
oTable = $('#userListTable').dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aLengthMenu": [5,10,25,50,100],
        "aoColumns": [ { 
        "bSortable": false }, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null,
                        null, { 
                        "bSortable": false } ]
                    });
        oTable.fnSort( [ [1,'asc'] ] );
});

function removeUser()
{
var ids = '';
$("input:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
          if (ids == '') {
                    ids += $(this).val();
          }else{
                    ids += ','+$(this).val();           
          }

});
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/userRemove/";
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
  '<input type="text" name="ids" value="' + ids + '" />' +
  '</form>');
console.log(form);
$('body').append(form);
if (ids != '') {
          form.submit();          
}else{
          alert('Select user to remove');
}

}
</script>

//some codes here

<button type="button" data-hover="tooltip" onclick="removeUser()" title="Delete Selected" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<button type="button" data-hover="tooltip" title="Add New User" class="btn btn-default">
        <div class="panel-header" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-1x"></i>
        </div>
</button>

// #myModal codes here

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.edit-row').live('click',function(){
                  var me = $(this);
                  var editModal = $('#myModalEdit');
                  editModal.find('#userID').val(me.attr('data-userID'));
                  editModal.find('#userName').val(me.attr('data-userName'));
                  editModal.find('#userFullName').val(me.attr('data-userFullName'));
                  editModal.find('#userPass').val(me.attr('data-userPass'));
                  editModal.find('#userEmail').val(me.attr('data-userEmail'));
                  $('#myModalEdit').modal('show');

                  });
                  });
</script>

//#myModalEdit codes here

<table id="userListTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" >
        <thead>
                        <tr>
                             <th><center><strong>#</strong></center></th>
                             <th><h4><strong>USER ID</strong></h4></th>
                             <th><h4><strong>FULL NAME</strong></h4></th>
                             <th><h4><strong>USERNAME</strong></h4></th>
                             <th><h4><strong>EMAIL</strong></h4></th>

                        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            if(!empty($data_user)):
            foreach($data_user as $row)
            {
                echo '<tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectAction" value="'.$row->userID.'" unchecked>
                </td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->userID.'</td>';
        ?>
        <td><a class="edit-row" href="javascript:" 
            data-userID="<?php echo $row->userID; ?>"
            data-userFullName="<?php echo $row->userFullName; ?>"
            data-userName="<?php echo $row->userName; ?>"
            data-userEmail="<?php echo $row->userEmail; ?>"
            >
            <?php echo $row->userFullName; ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <?php
            echo '<td>'.$row->userName.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->userEmail.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            }
            endif;
        ?>
      </tbody>
   </thead>
</table>

// other codes
```

application/controllers/Admin.php

```
public function userRemove() {
    $ids = $this->input->post('ids');

    if (!empty($ids)) {

        $this->db->where('userID IN (' . $this->input->post('ids') . ')')
            ->
        delete('user_tbl', $data);
    }

    redirect('userlist', 'refresh');
}
```

Edit and delete functions seems not working..

Comment: please put error here

Comment: I dont see any error.. its just not functioning.. when click on the button.. nothing happen .. :/